# .NET Flag Enum get Attributes from values

Tags: c#, .net, enums, custom-attributes

Greetings StackOverflow,

If I've got an enum type with the Flag attribute as well as the values in this enum type with their own attributes, how can I retrieve all of the appropriate attributes?

For example:

```
[Flags()]
enum MyEnum
{
    [EnumDisplayName("Enum Value 1")]
    EnumValue1 = 1,
    [EnumDisplayName("Enum Value 2")]
    EnumValue2 = 2,
    [EnumDisplayName("Enum Value 3")]
    EnumValue3 = 4,
}

void Foo()
{
    var enumVar = MyEnum.EnumValue2 | MyEnum.EnumValue3;

    // get a collection of EnumDisplayName attribute objects from enumVar
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick and dirty way using Linq:

```
IEnumerable<EnumDisplayNameAttribute> attributes = 
    Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))
        .Cast<MyEnum>()
        .Where(v => enumVar.HasFlag(v))
        .Select(v => typeof(MyEnum).GetField(v.ToString()))
        .Select(f => f.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumDisplayNameAttribute), false)[0])
        .Cast<EnumDisplayNameAttribute>();
```

Or in query syntax:

```
IEnumerable<EnumDisplayNameAttribute> attributes = 
    from MyEnum v in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))
    where enumVar.HasFlag(v)
    let f = typeof(MyEnum).GetField(v.ToString())
    let a = f.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumDisplayNameAttribute), false)[0]
    select ((EnumDisplayNameAttribute)a);
```

Alternatively, if there could possibly be multiple attributes on each field, you'll probably want to do this:

```
IEnumerable<EnumDisplayNameAttribute> attributes = 
    Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))
        .Cast<MyEnum>()
        .Where(v => enumVar.HasFlag(v))
        .Select(v => typeof(MyEnum).GetField(v.ToString()))
        .SelectMany(f => f.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumDisplayNameAttribute), false))
        .Cast<EnumDisplayNameAttribute>();
```

Or in query syntax:

```
IEnumerable<EnumDisplayNameAttribute> attributes = 
    from MyEnum v in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))
    where enumVar.HasFlag(v))
    let f = typeof(MyEnum).GetField(v.ToString())
    from EnumDisplayNameAttribute a in f.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumDisplayNameAttribute), false)
    select a;
```

Comment: I might need more coffee, but is the `Where(v => (enumVar & v) != v)` clause correct? Shouldn't it be `(enumVar & v) == v` or `(enumVar & v) != 0`? EDIT: Nevermind, let me get some coffee. EDITx2: No, I think I'm right. Oh god, I'm losing my mind.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Yes I had `!= 0` first, but then I realized `== v` might be better (but didn't fix the `!=`) but in fact `.HasFlag(v)` is better than both IMO. I guess I need coffee too :p

Comment: I use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of the indexer `[0]` to handle flags that maybe not have this attribute. Afterwards I check for null values in the list and react appropriately.